# Websphere AdminApp.edit script error

Tags: websphere-8

Previously in **WAS 7** we had a script to edit the roles of a user as below which worked just fine until the upgrade :

```
AdminApp.edit(appName, '[ -MapRolesToUsers [[ AppUser AppDeploymentOption.No AppDeploymentOption.No "" "" AppDeploymentOption.Yes "" "" ]]]')
```

but now in **WAS 8.5.5** this does not work and I want to map it to `AllAuthenticatedInTrustedRealms` I have tried n number of ways to do it as a sample :

```
AdminApp.edit(appName, '[ -MapRolesToUsers [[ AppUser No Yes "" "" "AllAuthenticatedInTrustedRealms" ]]]')
```

it keeps throwing the below error :

```
    WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "install_ear.py"; exception 
information: com.ibm.bsf.BSFException: exception from Jython:
Traceback (innermost last):
  (no code object) at line 0
  File "<string>", line 68
                AdminApp.edit(appName, '[ -MapRolesToUsers [[ AppUser No Yes ""
 "" "AllAuthenticatedInTrustedRealms" ]]]')
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Do you have access to the admin console? Can you configure this setting there and then click the "View administrative scripting command for last action" link on the right hand column?

Comment: yes i have configured *.ear from the console i need help in fixing the script.

Comment: Configure it once more from the console and then click the "View administrative scripting command for last action" link on the right hand pane once you set the setting but before you save to the master configuration. That will tell you what the valid syntax of the command should look like.

Comment: I clicked some listing and the link you said worked and showed me the command. Now i open AppServer/bin and enter `wsadmin` and run the command no update i refresh the page still nogo, kindly suggest.